# Cannot get JSON data into gridview

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have this code below and im trying to get the data `position and result` into my `searchlist` but when i try to put it in code here `GridView1.DataSource = list;` it keeps giving me an error `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.'` What im trying to accomplish is to get the data from `Weather and coord` into my gridview. I'm not sure why this keeps happening any help would be greatly appreciated

```
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public class Result
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string main { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string icon { get; set; }

        }


        public class SearchList
        {
            public Position coord { get; set; }
            public int resultCount { get; set; }
            public Result[] weather { get; set; }
        }
        public class Position
        {
            public double lon { get; set; }
            public double lat { get; set; }
        }


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchTerm = TextBox1.Text;
            var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+Server.UrlEncode(searchTerm)+"&units=metric&APPID=*Removed*");
            var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                string resString = sr.ReadToEnd();

                SearchList list = json.Deserialize<SearchList>(resString);

                GridView1.DataSource = list;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
                Label1.Text =
                "Invalid Response" ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be clear. What should the data look like in the grid?

Comment: What are you trying to bind? You need to update your question to be more clear.

Comment: If my assumption is accurate, Most likely you will have to convert that result into a projection to get the desired result, but you have not clarified what the data is suppose to look like in the grid

Comment: @Nkosi i have just updated my question

Comment: Grid views are for collections of data yet there is only one coordinate. How is the suppose to be used in the grid?

Comment: @Nkosi sorry but i dont get what you mean

Comment: Have you tried deserializing to a list before your data bind?   
SearchList list = json.Deserialize<List<SearchList>>(resString);

Comment: @BestJeanist weather property is an array (a collection) so it shows fine in the grid on it own. How does the coord property relate to the weather data?

Comment: @Nkosi ahh yes i understand but how do i display the coord property if its not an array

Comment: depends on what you want. you can put it in another control or repeat it for each item in the array. Each approach would determine how you present it in the UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What im trying to accomplish is to get the data from Weather and coord into my gridview.

If you want to include all the data in the grid then you will need to project it to a type that includes everything.

```
using System.Linq;

//...

//... code removed for brevity 

var list = json.Deserialize<SearchList>(resString);

var data = list.weather.Select(item => new {
    lon = list.coord.lon,
    lat = list.coord.lat,
    id = item.id,
    main = item.main,
    description = item.description,
    icon = item.icon
});

GridView1.DataSource = data;
GridView1.DataBind();

//... code removed for brevity
```

This means that the `lon` and `lat` will be repeated for each item in the `weather` property.

If those properties were meant to be displayed on their own then populate another control.

Answer (score 0):

`list` is just an instance of `SearchList` and thus does not implement `IEnumerable` or other interfaces mentioned in the exception (essentially any `List`, `Array` or other strongly typed collection).

If you want to show coordinates in the grid, then they should be properties in your `Result` type.

```
 GridView1.DataSource = list.weather;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

If you only intend to show a single coordinate, then you should rethink your choice of controls or add additional controls such as a `Label`

```
[coords] {list.Position} - Label
[id, name, description, icon] {list.weather[0]} - GridViewRow
[id, name, description, icon] {list.weather[1]} - GridViewRow
[id, name, description, icon] {list.weather[2]} - GridViewRow
```

Comment: I have tried that but it only returns me the value of {id,main,description,icon} it does not display the coord values

Comment: updated my answer. you need to be more clear on what you want to bind.